# unable to pass data from views to js file having chart js codes, shows unexpected syntax error

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, chart.js, django-queryset

I am trying to make analytics for my webapp, where it whould show data from db graphically. I am using chart js for this. I am learning how to do it from youtube. Strangely they are not getting any error where as I am getting this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
```

these are the codes that I have written

**views.py**

```
 monthly_visitor = VisitorCount.objects.all().values(
    'date_of_record__month'
    ).annotate(
        total_in_month=Count('ip') # take visitor_id or whatever you want to count
        ).order_by()

    yearly_visitor = VisitorCount.objects.all().values('date_of_record__year').annotate(
        total_in_year= Count('ip')
    ).order_by()

    print("\nthe values of monthly visitors are", monthly_visitor, "\n")

    visitorMonthNumber = []
    visitorNumberMonthly = []

    
    for i in range(len(monthly_visitor)):

        visitorMonthNumber.append(monthly_visitor[i]['date_of_record__month'])
        visitorNumberMonthly.append(monthly_visitor[i]['total_in_month'])   
    
    print("\nthis is the list of month number =", visitorMonthNumber, "\n", "\nthis is the number of visitors", visitorNumberMonthly, "\n")
       

    
     context = {
        'visitorMonthNumber':  visitorMonthNumber,
        'visitorNumberMonthly':  visitorNumberMonthly
    }

    return render(request, "chart.html", context)
```

In the above code I am querying a model named visitor count to get the number of visitors on every month.

**js file**

```
var visitorMonthNumber = {{visitorMonthNumber}};
var visitorNumberMonthly = {{visitorNumberMonthly}};
const visitorM = document.getElementById('visitorMonthly').getContext('2d');
const visitorMonthly = new Chart(visitorM, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: visitorMonthNumber,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Monthly Visitors',
            data: visitorNumberMonthly,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have no idea how to get this data rendered graphically. Please correct me where I am going wrong.

**this code prints**

```
print("\nthis is the list of month number =", visitorMonthNumber, "\n", "\nthis is the number of visitors", visitorNumberMonthly, "\n")
```

**this result** and this is what i want to get rendered in my chart

```
this is the list of month number = [12, 10, 11, 9, 1]

this is the number of visitors [3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: ***``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'``*** - means you have extra or may not have ``{`` this in your javascript

Comment: okay, but they are calling it jinja format, and using this somehow their's getting rendered but no mine

Comment: Okk, you've to put these values ``{{visitorMonthNumber}}`` ``{{visitorNumberMonthly}}`` in string like this ``"{{visitorMonthNumber}}"`` ``"{{visitorNumberMonthly}}"`` and if you're doing some arithmetic operations on these tow values than convert it into interger format like this ``parseInt("{{visitorNumberMonthly}}") ``

Comment: just tried this but this is not giving me the values that i passed from views, it just rendering out the letters enclosed in quotes

Comment: Actually I was writing about that check my previous comment I've edited it

Comment: the error is gone but I am not getting the list that I have passed from views

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240393/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-ritankar-bhattacharjee).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

Either pass the values inside the **context** to the html and then use the script text inside the html file to render out the data.

Another method, and perhaps the accurate one is to use ajax.